# Global Library in Crontab PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, sh, cron

Is it possible to include `global $_lib, $_SETUP;` in crontab?

I have a cronjob writting in php file in internet directory (/internet/mycrontab.php), but seem like the crontab throws error when I using $_Lib like in `$_lib['db']->db_fetch_object($query)`.

The $_Lib working fine if I enter the url directly in browser www.myweb.dom/internet/mycrontab.php, and the crontab also working fine if I remove the $_Lib like in `$_lib['db']->db_fetch_object($query)` by using hardcode sysntax (primary).

If it is possible to include `global $_lib, $_SETUP;`, how do I correctly do that?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the crontab environment and your web app environment are different things.

The cronjob is run by php-cli while the app is run by apache (or NGINX, whatever) php module.

You should probably evaluate to include your library into the crontab file.

```
include "/path/to/your/library.php";
$_lib = "whatever";
$_SETUP = "whatever";
```

Without having a proper look at the code that's the best I can suggest.

Comment: Usually we only include it by declare the `global $_lib, $_SETUP` without need to include the path. Do I shall include the path, too? Thank you very much for the respond.

Comment: Try. Probably the php-cli conf file is different from the one you have for your app

Comment: Even if it is working by including the clear path, I still curious to make it simple by just using `global $_lib, $_SETUP`, because the crontab is everywhere in our server (in many web/app/vhost). That is what I am thinking If it can be helped by configure something in crontab config file.

Comment: I would avoid global, but you can add the library in the include part of the .ini file.